# Number of distinct elements in array using bits in int

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have this code 
what is wrong in my code
it must display how many distinct elements are there

```
string name;
long long maps;
int i,j,test,l,counts=0,k;
cin>>test;
for(i=0;i<test;i++){
        counts=maps=0;
        cin>>name;
        l = name.length();
        for(j=0;j<l;j++){
            k=(toupper(name[j])-'A');
            cout<<endl<<(maps&(1<<k))<<" "<<k;
            if(0 == maps&(1<<k)){
                    counts++;
                    maps|=(1<<k);
            }else{
                cout<<" "<<(int)(maps&(1<<k))==0;
            }
        }
        cout<<counts;
}
```

what is wrong check witht the output i cant find why i is not working

Comment: _" what is wrong in my code it must display how many distinct elements are there"_ Yes, what **is** wrong? What does it do instead of what you want? Did you really thing this was a problem description: _"what is wrong check witht the output i cant find why i is not working"_ Also, the code is incomplete: no includes, no `main()`, so there's not much  point in guessing what you're doing wrong even if you had given a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if(0 == maps&(1<<k)){
```

The equality operator `==` has higher precedence than the bitwise-AND operator `&`.  So the above evaluates to this:

```
if ((0 == maps) & (1 << k )) {
```

You need to add parenthesis to get the desired behavior:

```
if (0 == (maps & (1 << k))) {
```

You'll need to do the same in your `cout` call:

```
cout<<" "<<(int)((maps&(1<<k))==0);
```

Comment: bro i tried it. It worked for me thanks but the interchanged